# Simplest way of counting the length of items in a list of lists and displaying the result as a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Is there a more scalable way of counting the length of each item in this list of lists, and still showing the outcome as a list of lists?
my current solution feels excessively long and not scalable (i'm always going to have to type the index of each list)

```
mylist = [['C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Swift'], ['Software','Web','Mobile'], ['Microsoft', 'Oracle', 'OpenSource', 'Apple', 'SAP']]
l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []
l = [l1, l2, l3]
for n in mylist[0]:
    c = len(n)
    l1.append(c)
for n in mylist[1]:
    c = len(n)
    l2.append(c)
for n in mylist[2]:
    c = len(n)
    l3.append(c)
print(l)
```

The correct output is:

```
[[3, 4, 6, 5], [8, 3, 6], [9, 6, 10, 5, 3]]
```

I tried using a single for loop, but it shows the results in a single list, not in a list of lists.

```
l = []
for i in mylist:
    for n in i:
        c = len(n)
        l.append(c)
print(l)
```

Also tried a while loop, but the program quit as an infinite loop.

```
mylist = [['C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Swift'], ['Software','Web','Mobile'], ['Microsoft', 'Oracle', 'OpenSource', 'Apple', 'SAP']]
l = []
i = 0
n = 0
while i < len(mylist):
    while n < len(mylist[i]):
        c = len(mylist[i][n])
        l.append(c)
    fl = [l]
    l = []
    i += 1
print(fl)
```

Comment: `print([[len(s) for s in l] for l in mylist])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is a simple nested list comprehension:

```
output = [[len(element) for element in sublist] for sublist in mylist]
```

You can use a single loop if you delegate some work to `map`:

```
output = [list(map(len, sublist)) for sublist in mylist]
```

If you want to have some fun you can use `map` twice:

```
output = list(map(lambda sublist: list(map(len, sublist)), mylist))
```

Comment: For me, `list(map(lambda` is the *opposite* of fun :-P

Comment: Thanks! The nested list comprehension was enough!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```
res = [[len(y) for y in x] for x in mylist]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[3, 4, 6, 5], [8, 3, 6], [9, 6, 10, 5, 3]]
```